# Assign empty string to a property with a currently value of nothing

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework-4, string

In my EF4 EntityModel I have an entity named USERS. USERS have the common UserName and Password string fields. If I do something like this:

```
Dim u as new USERS  
U.UserName = String.Empty
```

Then U.UserName is still nothing. But if I do something like this:

```
Dim u as new USERS   
u.UserName = “A”   
u.UserName = String.Empty
```

then U.UserName takes String.Empty as value without problem.

The reason is the way that EF4 generates the UserName Property

```
Public Property UserName() As Global.System.String  
    Get  
        Return _UserName  
    End Get  
    Set  
        If (_UserName <> Value) Then    ‘Here is the key  
            OnUserNameChanging(value)  
            ReportPropertyChanging("UserName")  
            _UserName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false)  
            ReportPropertyChanged("UserName")  
                OnUserNameChanged()  
            End If  
        End Set  
    End Property
```

My question is:

How can I deal with it?

Is there something I can do to avoid this behavior? I do not want to make two assignations every time I want to set string.empty to a property with a nothing value, and I do not want to remember that I must do it in this way every time, because I'm pretty sure that I will forget it and then I will introduce bugs in the code. I just want to assign the empty.string value to a property and the property take “” as value.

As I come from C# and I'm a newbie in vb.net, I really hope that I’was missing something.

Comment: Thanks SLaks... I've been trying to format propertly this code for 10 minutes...

Comment: what's the context? Do you need the OnPropertyChanged behaviour (like in a WPF app with binding)? There are 3 code gen templates as alternatives, and that'll dictate which one is for you.

Comment: @RichardW1001: I do not need the OnPropertyChanged Interface to be implemented, I just choose the defalt template because I'm starting with EF4.

Comment: Consider the POCO code generator in that case, nice and clean and simple. Right click your diagram and choose "Add Code Generation", and go for the POCO one. If you don't have it installed, it'd be an add in from the Visual Studio Extension Manager (Tools --> Extension Manager), under Templates --> Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you definitely want to assign an empty string instead of an empty value? If not you could just set the property to be nullable?

Either way you can manipulate the code that EF generates by using T4 templates (VS calls them Code Generators), so you could change the property setter implementation to whatever you wanted by doing that.

Edit - adding a bit more detail

If you use the POCO generator, you get plain properties, i.e. no property changed etc

If you use the EntityObject generator, it basically lets you edit the generation you currently have. If you use a T4 add in for visual studio you get syntax highlighting on the T4, there are some free ones available in the VS2010 add ins which are very good. You basically have code that generates code there, which you can tweak. the line you flagged is on line 523:

```
If (<#=code.FieldName(primitiveProperty)#> <> Value) Then
```

You could try and do something funky based on type, or you could just revert to using Object.Equals(), or whatever else you want, instead of this line. Or you could remove the If section entirely but that might have other consequences. When you save the T4 template, it'll update all the generated code for you.

Depending what you are actually doing, the POCO template might cure your problem.

BTW if you want more on T4, visit Oleg Sych's blog, http://www.olegsych.com/tag/t4/ .

Comment: Of course, I could modify the T4 template, or even write some kind of workarround. The first option will involve too much complexity (distribute the template along the programming team, etc) and the second one is not elegant. I supossed that I was missing something, but if it is not the case then there is no other option, I will choose one of the alternatives. The main goal is to avoid that this default behaviour don't cause bugs in our codes, bacause The described situation happens will all the entities in the model.

Comment: Sounds like a strong case for the vanilla POCO generator. BTW the T4 template sits in your solution, so distributing it wouldn't necessarily be a big issue. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the details added! :D I will search for the template and the line that you specified. I Use Tangible editor for T4 templates in order to gain syntax highlighting. I did some T4 templates in the past, so I Think this could be a way to solve the problem. I can't use POCO because I need object persistence.

Comment: Finally, the solution rewrite in the T4 the line that you told me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<del>The problem is that string comparison in VB treats `Nothing` and the empty string as equal. You can circumvent this by explicitly using `String.Equals`.</del>

```
If Not String.Equals(_UserName, Value) Then …
```

<del>Better yet, forbid `Nothing` values completely and initialize the field inside the class to the value of `""` (or `String.Empty`, if you must … which is more or less equivalent).</del>

**/EDIT: file a bug report. The generator that generated this code is broken.**

Comment: @SLaks: then the generator is broken. :-(

Comment: Don't edit this on individual generated classes, as next time you save your model they'll over-write! Also, this only works for String, whereas the EF generated implementation has to be generic because it deals with all value types.

Comment: I wouldn't say the generator is broken, it's just working differently to the specific behaviour you want. Edit one of the generator templates to implement different behaviour.

Comment: @Richard: you’re right. I was overreacting. In reality I suspect it’s the VB semantics of string comparison that is broken to accomodate migrating VB6 users but that’s a different topic.

Comment: @Konrad - Don't think that would be it, EF properties can be quite a few different types, and so they went for the generic comparator. String.Equals() would obviously work great for strings, but for integer/double/GUID/binary/date... whatever other type of property, it'll fall short, whereas the a <> b is always available.